# How to hide md-tab using style display none

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using md-tabs in my project and I am adding custom directive to hide and show the tab. I have tried like this below

```
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-autoselect md-selected="quesCtrl.selectTab.activeMainTabIdx">
                    <md-tab label="question Add" ui-sref="questionsAdd">
                        <div ui-view class="marg-top30"></div>
                    </md-tab>
                    <md-tab label="upload Question" ui-sref="uploadQuestions">
                        <div ui-view class="marg-top30"></div>
                    </md-tab>
                    <md-tab label="My Questions" ui-sref="saved" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}">
                        <div ui-view class="marg-top30"></div>
                    </md-tab>
                    <div>
                        <md-tab has-permission="AUQUE" label="Author Questions" ui-sref="authorsubmitted" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}">
                            <div ui-view class="marg-top30"></div>
                        </md-tab>
                    </div>
                    
                </md-tabs>
```

and my directive is like

```
    (function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('iceOnGo.Admin')
           .directive('hasPermission', HasPermission);

    function HasPermission(rPermissionService) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                if (!_.isString(attrs.hasPermission)) {
                    throw 'hasPermission value must be a string'
                }
                var value = attrs.hasPermission.trim();
                var notPermissionFlag = value[0] === '!';
                if (notPermissionFlag) {
                    value = value.slice(1).trim();
                }

                function toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission() {
                    rPermissionService.HasPermissions(value).then(function (hasPermission) {
                 // if hasPermission is true then the element has to visible otherwise not

                    if (hasPermission && !notPermissionFlag || !hasPermission && notPermissionFlag) {
                        element[0].style.display = 'block';
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        element[0].style.display = 'none';
                        
                    }
                    });
                }

                toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission();
                scope.$on('permissionsChanged', toggleVisibilityBasedOnPermission);
            }
        };
    }

    HasPermission.$inject = [
        'iceOnGo.RolePermissionsService'
    ];

})();
```

md-tab element has style display none but it's not working. could any please tell me how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of targeting elements like that why don't you do it the angular way?

This means on the md-tab element add an ng-if or an ng-show something like this:

```
<md-tab ng-if="visible === true">
    <div ui-view class="marg-top30"></div>
</md-tab>
```

`visible` is a boolean flag you set in the directive based on your permission logic.

something like :

```
if (hasPermission && !notPermissionFlag || !hasPermission && notPermissionFlag) {
    visible = true;
} else {
    visible = false;
}
```

then you don't have to worry about setting any style. Note the difference between `ng-if` and `ng-show`. `ng-if` removes the element from the dom completely while `ng-show` applies the same method as what you are doing now, changes the `style.display` to none.

Example is untested, if you had provided a fiddle then I would have tried it. Hopefully you get the idea even if the code is not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Try by adding/removing the *ng-hide* css class

If does not work, try with this (you can see the running sample here https://jsfiddle.net/llezcano/7vovqrj1/)

```
function hasPermission (RolePermissionsService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var setVisible = function () {
        console.log("visible");
        element.removeClass('ng-hide');
      },
      setHidden = function () {
        console.log("hidden");
        element.addClass('ng-hide');
      },
      defineVisibility = function (reset) {
        if (reset) {
          setVisible();
        }
        RolePermissionsService.HasPermissions(authority)
        .then(function (result) {
          if (result) {
            setVisible();
          } else {
            setHidden();
          }
        });
      },
      authority = attrs.hasPermission.replace(/\s+/g, '');

      if (authority.length > 0) {
        defineVisibility(true);

        scope.$on('permissionsChanged', function() {
          defineVisibility(true);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I took the [has-authority](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/v2.x_maintenance/app/templates/src/main/webapp/scripts/components/auth/_authority.directive.js) from the jHipster generator and adapted it to your needs.

Comment: I hope ng-hide will do the same, like putting style.display:none. but md-tab doesn't accepting style.display:none

Comment: You can try with the !important rule, in a new css class. 
.my-hide {
   display:none !important;
}  And use "my-hide" instead "ng-hide"

Answer (score 1):

It is easy by the combination of ng-disable and CSS display none. First of all add an id to the container, for example, BAR.

```
<div id="BAR"> ... </div>
```

Then add ng- disable to tabs:

```
<md-tab ng-disable="visibleFlag" ...>
```

And finally, add the following CSS:

```
#BAR .md-tab.md-disabled {
  display: none;
}
```